# Ruby not getting any cipher from openssl

Tags: ruby, openssl

I have ruby-2.6.2, and openssl@1.1 installed in my Mac. However Ruby is not getting any ssl ciphers.

From the console I run this:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS
# => {:min_version=>769, :verify_mode=>1, :verify_hostname=>true, :options=>2147614804}
```

In the output I was expecting a list of ciphers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer Ruby versions (>= 2.4), and when using OpenSSL 1.1 or newer, Ruby doesn't explicitly override OpenSSL's default set of ciphers anymore as was done in previous versions. Previously, this was necessary since older OpenSSL versions included some insecure ciphers by default.

With newer versions, Ruby relies on OpenSSL's default ciphers unless explicitly overwritten by yourself. You can get those by e.g. running `openssl ciphers -v 'DEFAULT:!PSK:!SRP'` on your shell.

This behavior was changed (and explained) in the respective pull request at https://github.com/ruby/openssl/pull/66.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct, and you could not expect anything else.

Source:

```rb
DEFAULT_PARAMS = { # :nodoc:
  :min_version => OpenSSL::SSL::TLS1_VERSION,
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
  :verify_hostname => true,
  :options => -> {
    opts = OpenSSL::SSL::OP_ALL
    opts &= ~OpenSSL::SSL::OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS
    opts |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION
    opts
   }.call
}
```

Maybe you mean `Ciphers`?
In this case use:

```rb
puts OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers
```

Or use this:

```rb
puts `openssl ciphers -v 'DEFAULT:!PSK:!SRP'`
```